# Want to create and get server time in application without saving into Firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set server time in Firestore database in `Long` format. I have tried to create timestamp using below code, it seems like it creates just reference of the `FieldValue`.

```
val dataMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
dataMap["createdOn"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Is there any way to create server time and convert it into required format?

Comment: @Ashish It just shows FieldValue$ServerTimestampFieldValue@11736

Comment: @Alex: The output we try to achieve is get server time without saving into Firestore database.

Comment: Check the second duplicate.

Comment: @AlexMamo: ServeValue has five options:
SERVER_VALUE_UNSPECIFIED(0),
REQUEST_TIME(1),
UNRECOGNIZED(-1);
SERVER_VALUE_UNSPECIFIED_VALUE
REQUEST_TIME_VALUE

But not able to find TIMESTAMP in it.